# Hibernate Search 6 with Infinispan Directory Provider

Tags: hibernate-search, infinispan, hibernate-search-6

Can't find any information about the Infinispan directory provider in the Hibernate Search 6.0 documentation.

See: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single

Does this mean, the Infinispan directory provider is not supported anymore since version 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean, the Infinispan directory provider is not supported anymore since version 6.0?

It does.

The Infinispan directory provider was [deprecated in Infinispan 10.1](https://infinispan.org/docs/10.1.x/titles/upgrading/upgrading.html#infinispan_lucene_directory_is_deprecated) and [removed in Infinispan 11](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/pull/8137/files#diff-660ba6629daad34b653ab761530bda33edb1c169ee33f9e78222f1a7a411616c).

There are plans to [provide an actual Infinispan backend](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-882) in Hibernate Search 6, one that would use the Infinispan APIs to index documents and run search queries instead of just storing indexes on Infinispan. But work on this backend hasn't started yet.

In the meantime, if you want a distributed search index, you can always use the [Elasticsearch backend](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#elasticsearch-integration).